# Scala convert map k -> (v1,v2) to single Key-value pair

Tags: scala, dictionary, keyvaluepair

How would be the method to perform the following operation?

Convert a Map `K1->(v1,v2), K2->(v1,v2)` to `K1->v1,K1->v2,K2->v1,K2->V2`

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: do you want 4 maps as the answer? because in the same map there can't be more than one key.

Comment: @RamanMishra Yes, 4 different Maps

Comment: Are the values a tuple (a 2-ple) or is that supposed to represent a collection such as a `List` for example.

Comment: The values are a tuple2 @jwvh

Comment: Convert Map[String,(String,String)] to Map[String, String]

Answer (score 1):

To go from `Map[String,(String, String)]` to `List[Map[String,String]]`:

```
val mss = Map("s"->("a","b"), "t"->("a","c"))

mss.toList.flatMap{case (k,(a,b)) => List((k,a),(k,b))}.map(Map(_))
```

The last step of turning every result tuple into a `Map` is pretty pointless. What's the use of a `Map` with only one key->value pair?

Answer (score 0):

You should firstly convert your `Map` to `List` or to `Seq` (if you want more general type) and then you can use `flatMap`. The example with `toList`:

```
val map = Map("a" -> ("1", "2"), "b" -> ("3", "4"))

map.toList.flatMap {
  case (k, (v1, v2)) => List(k -> v1, k -> v2)
}
// res0: List[(String, String)] = List((a,1), (a,2), (b,3), (b,4))
```

Firstly your values mapped into lists of tuples, so the intermediate result will be:

`List(List((a,1), (a,2)), List((b,3), (b,4)))`

and then it *flattens* and you get list of tuples:

`List((a,1), (a,2), (b,3), (b,4))`

Comment: And what if I want to convert that List to a map? If I try with .toMap method it just get the (k,v) with last v seen and I want to keep them

Comment: You can't do that because of `Map`, this data structure can have only unique keys. Please, read [this](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/maps.html) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) articles

Comment: If you want to keep your values, leave them in a tuple. You can also store them in a list or in another `SeqLike` data structure, so your map might look like `Map[String, Seq[String]]`.